# Magento : add attributes by code

Tags: magento

i m beginner to magento (developping extention) and i wanna add two fields under Tax Class :

[image]

```
________
```

how can i do this ?

note: i've searched for while and tried with no result

Comment: Souf, Are you want to add new attribute or another options in tax class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily add the custom Product Attributes By go to the following location

Catalog->Attributes-> Manage Attributes.

Please Refer the Following Link for detailed steps to create the Product Attributes.

http://michaelarney.blogspot.in/2010/12/add-attribute-to-product-in-magento.html

Comment: i know how to add it this way i saw that button up "Create new Attribute" i did created it it worked but what i want is to do that by code !

Comment: for that you need to create the setup script. Please refer the following link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928298/adding-custom-product-attributes-in-magento-using-setup-script

Comment: ok i followed the tuto that he followed and it worked same code i didn't change now i need to add attributes to an existing group not special attributes

Comment: you want to add the attribute to the existing attribute set?

Comment: ok thats cool i did it like this :
$setup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'min_price', array(
 'group' => 'Prices', ....etc));