# setup installer script in magento module

Tags: sql, magento, module, installation

Hi i am developing a little magento module.

below is my directory structure of module

```
app/code/local/Xyz/Total
/var/www/magext/app/code/local/Xyz/Total/Block/Prototal.php
/var/www/magext/app/code/local/Xyz/Total/controllers/IndexController.php
/var/www/magext/app/code/local/Xyz/Total/etc/config.xml
/var/www/magext/app/code/local/Xyz/Total/Model/Price/Observer.php
```

below is my config file code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <global>
      <blocks>
         <total>
              <class>Xyz_Total_Block</class>
         </total>
      </blocks>   


    <models>
        <xyztotal>
             <class>Xyz_Total_Model</class>
        </xyztotal>
    </models>
    <events>
      <sales_order_place_after>
        <observers>
          <xyz_total_price_observer>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Xyz_Total_Model_Price_Observer</class>
            <method>apply_discount_percent</method>
          </xyz_total_price_observer>
        </observers>
      </sales_order_place_after>     
    </events>
  </global>
 <frontend>
   <routers>
      <total>
          <use>standard</use>
          <args>
             <module>Xyz_Total</module>
             <frontName>newcatalog</frontName>
          </args>
       </total>
   </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <total>
                 <file>total.xml</file>
             </total>
        </updates>
    </layout>

</frontend>
</config>
```

> now what i need to install a product attribute through my module
>
> .But i cant understand understand where should i put my installer
>   script and how to modify config file.

please suggest.

Comment: Please read this [**blog**](http://vishallakhani.wordpress.com/2012/10/05/how-to-add-or-create-product-attribute-dynamically-in-magento/)

Comment: i have check  can you please tell me 
app/code/local/Packagename/Modulename/sql/module_setp/mysql 0.1.1.0

in this module_setp should it be same like this

Comment: it should be `{module_name}_setup` I suppose. For example, if the module name is Xyz then `Xyz_setup`.

Comment: I just found another [**blog**](http://pravams.com/2011/06/28/magento-create-attributes-dynamically/).

Comment: HI i have created a file
/var/www/magext/app/code/local/Xyz/Total/sql/total_setup/mysql4-install-0.0.1.php  but it has not run any script and create any attribute

Comment: do we need to make any change in xml file also

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about this. I hope those blog links were somehow helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your config.xml i am not able to find xml vesrion.
So you need to give xml version like below example:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Xyz_Total>
            <version>0.1.0</version>    <!-- Version of module -->
        </Xyz_Total>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Now create the file app/code/local/Xyz/Total/sql/total_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.ph‌​p
After that reinstall the module And check it.

Comment: please check that you havn't gave module version twice.
once in a app\etc\modules\Xyz_Total.xml.
Second time in your module config.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to add below code in config.xml under config tag.

```
<global>
    <resources>  <!-- These are resource setting giving access to module, read/write permission on database -->
        <total_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Xyz_Total</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </total_setup>
        <total_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </total_write>
        <total_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </total_read>
    </resources>
</global>
```

After that reinstall module.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look @ [Adding custom product attributes in Magento using setup script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928298/adding-custom-product-attributes-in-magento-using-setup-script)

```
<modules>
    <Xyz_Total>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Xyz_Total>
</modules>
<global>
  ....   
  <models>
    <xyztotal>
         <class>Xyz_Total_Model</class>
         <resourceModel>total_setup</resourceModel>
    </xyztotal>
  </models>
  <resources>
     <catalog_setup>
        <setup>
           <module>Mage_Catalog</module>
           <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class><!-- that line !-->
        </setup>
     </catalog_setup>
  </resources>
...
```

In

> app/code/local/Xyz/Total/sql/total_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.ph‌​p

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'offer_type', array(
        'backend'       => '',
        ...
));
```