# Magento - Programmatically create custom product attribute via set up script

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to run a script that creates additional product attribute in magento admin. However the attribute doesn't come out to the admin backend.

This is my model: `Setup.php`

```
class Rts_Cattribute_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup
{
protected function _prepareValues($attr)
{
    $data = parent::_prepareValues($attr);
    $data = array_merge($data, array(

        'apply_to'                      => $this->_getValue($attr, 'apply_to'),
        'frontend_input_renderer'       => $this->_getValue($attr, 'input_renderer'),
        'is_comparable'                 => $this->_getValue($attr, 'comparable', 0),
        'is_configurable'               => $this->_getValue($attr, 'is_configurable', 1),
        'is_filterable'                 => $this->_getValue($attr, 'filterable', 0),
        'is_filterable_in_search'       => $this->_getValue($attr, 'filterable_in_search', 0),
        'is_global'                     => $this->_getValue(
            $attr,
            'global',
            Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_WEBSITE
        ),
        'is_html_allowed_on_front'      => $this->_getValue($attr, 'is_html_allowed_on_front', 0),
        'is_searchable'                 => $this->_getValue($attr, 'searchable', 0),
        'is_used_for_promo_rules'       => $this->_getValue($attr, 'used_for_promo_rules', 0),
        'is_visible'                    => $this->_getValue($attr, 'visible', 1),
        'is_visible_on_front'           => $this->_getValue($attr, 'visible_on_front', 1),
        'is_wysiwyg_enabled'            => $this->_getValue($attr, 'wysiwyg_enabled', 0),
        'is_visible_in_advanced_search' => $this->_getValue($attr, 'visible_in_advanced_search', 0),
        'position'                      => $this->_getValue($attr, 'position', 0),
        'used_for_sort_by'              => $this->_getValue($attr, 'used_for_sort_by', 0),
        'used_in_product_listing'       => $this->_getValue($attr, 'used_in_product_listing', 0)
    ));
    return $data;
}
}
```

This is my config: `config.xml`

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Rts_Cattribute>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Rts_Cattribute>
</modules>
<global>
    <resources>
        <cattribute_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Rts_Cattribute</module>
                <class>Rts_Cattribute_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </cattribute_setup>
    </resources>
</global>
</config>
```

Lastly this is my install script: `mysql4-install-0.1.0.php`

```
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'max_ftlbs', array(
    'type'              => 'int',
    'backend'           => '',
    'frontend'          => '',
    'label'             => 'Max Ft.Lbs',
    'input'             => 'text',
    'class'             => '',
    'source'            => '',
    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible'           => false,
    'required'          => false,
    'user_defined'      => false,
    'default'           => '',
    'searchable'        => false,
    'filterable'        => false,
    'comparable'        => false,
    'visible_on_front'  => false,
    'unique'            => false,
    'apply_to'          => '',
    'is_configurable'   => false
));

$installer->endSetup();
```

I followed this tutorials

http://magento4newbies.blogspot.com/2015/01/how-to-adding-custom-product-attributes.html

http://codegento.com/2011/02/install-scripts-and-upgrade-scripts/

In this link [Adding custom product attributes in Magento using setup script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928298/adding-custom-product-attributes-in-magento-using-setup-script)
it says that The standard class for magento installers is `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup` but when dealing with products, you'll need to use `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup` instead.

I've tried many solution however it didn't work.

Everytime I do some changes I always delete the resource version before I refresh the page.

### Problem:

The custom attribute won't show up or it is not created in the admin backend.

### Question:

What is the right standard class for magento installer?

Is my installer correct?

I hope you can help me with this.

Comment: Do you have the xml file in app/etc/modules?
e.g. Rts_Cattribute.xml
<modules>
    <Rts_Cattribute>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
   </Rts_Cattribute>
</modules>

Comment: Yes, I already included it, however the attribute don't display but the version was already in the core_resource.

Comment: Maybe you need to reindex and clear the cache. Have you checked the attribute in the DB?

Comment: I always clear my cache but the attribute was not created however the version was registered on the core_resource table.

Comment: If you ran the setup once, and a row is in the setup table for your version, the setup script won't run a second time. You need to remove that from the database.

Answer (score 1):

One thing i noticed I had to do was put the db connection info in the config.xml class.

```
<catalog_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>XX_YY</module>
                <class>XX_YY_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </catalog_setup>
        <catalog_setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </catalog_setup>
        <catalog_setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </catalog_setup>
```

Also in the installer class I set installer equal to this:

```
$installer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup','catalog_setup');
```

Answer (score 1):

For Create Product Attribute no need to create Module just run below script in your Magento root folder.

```
<?php  

require_once('app/Mage.php');
 Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));

$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();                   

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'max_ftlbs', array(
     'type'              => 'int',
     'backend'           => '',
     'frontend'          => '',
     'label'             => 'Max Ft.Lbs',
     'input'             => 'text',
     'class'             => '',
     'source'            => '',
     'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
     'visible'           => false,
     'required'          => false,
     'user_defined'      => false,
     'default'           => '',
     'searchable'        => false,
     'filterable'        => false,
     'comparable'        => false,
     'visible_on_front'  => false,
     'unique'            => false,
     'apply_to'          => '',
     'is_configurable'   => false
));

$installer->endSetup();

?>
```

For Remove Product Attribute

```
<?php  

require_once('app/Mage.php');
 Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
 $installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup;
 $installer->startSetup();
 $installer->removeAttribute('catalog_product', 'max_ftlbs');
 $installer->endSetup();

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the script to create the custom attribute you need to run the script each time when you are moving the files from one database to another (Local-Staging-Live ).

But we create using the module it is very easy to maintain and manage.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial gives step by step explanation of how to add custom product attribute and the file structure using setup script.

http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/adding-custom-product-attributes-in-magento-using-setup-script/

```
<?php
$this->startSetup();
$this->addAttribute(catalog_product, 'featured_product', array(
'group'         => 'General',
'input'         => 'select',
'type'          => 'text',
'label'         => 'Featured Product',
'backend'       => '',
'visible'       => true,
'required'      => false,
'visible_on_front' => true,
'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
'source' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
'sort_order'        => 8,
));

$this->endSetup();
```