# Magento - How do I grab data from observer model

Tags: php, magento, model, block, observers

I'm trying to create a simple product selector. The the post data from form was transfer to controller to observer. If I var_dump in observer, the data was present however I can't access it on my block class.

This is my controller:

```
public function indexAction() {

    $session  = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');

    if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {

        $data['ta'] = $this->getRequest()->getPost('torqueAction');
        $data['tr'] = $this->getRequest()->getPost('torqueRequired');
        $data['tm'] = $this->getRequest()->getPost('torqueMetric');

        $eventdata = $data;
        Mage::dispatchEvent('selector_custom_event', $eventdata);
    }
    $this->_redirect('prodselector/index/result');
}

public function resultAction() {
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

This is my observer

```
public function observe($observer) {
$event = $observer->getEvent();

$test = $event->getData();

return $test;
}
```

This is my block:

```
public function getSelectedProducts() {

$arr_products = array();
$products = Mage::getModel("prodselector/observer")->observe();

return $arr_products;
}
```

This is how I test on the phtml:

```
<?php var_dump($this->getSelectedProducts()); ?>
```

I got an error everytime I execute the module

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getEvent() on a non-object in app/code/local/Rts/Prodselector/Model/Observer.php on line 6
```

PROBLEM:

I can't access the the data from the observer via block class to phtml and I don't understand the error.

QUESTION:

What is the meaning of this error?

How do I access the data from the observer via block class to phtml?

Is my process correct?

Can you give me some guide?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to fetch products in the block, but there are no data.

I recommend the better solution for you:

Controller:

```
public function indexAction() {

    $session  = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');

    if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {

        $ta = $this->getRequest()->getPost('torqueAction');
        $tr = $this->getRequest()->getPost('torqueRequired');
        $tm = $this->getRequest()->getPost('torqueMetric');
        $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addFieldToFilter('torque_action', $ta)
            ->addFieldToFilter('torque_required', $tr)
            ->addFieldToFilter('torque_metric', $tm);
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setTorqueProductCollection($productCollection);
    }
    $this->_redirect('prodselector/index/result');
}

public function resultAction() {
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

In the block:

```
public function getSelectedProducts() {
    $products = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getTorqueProductCollection();
    return $products;
}
```

In the template:

```
<?php foreach ($this->getSelectedProducts() as $product) : ?>
    <?php print_r($product->getName());
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This should not be done by events.

Comment: Thanks @Marko Novakovic for your reply. I tried this process before and I tried it again using the codes you provided, however the    $products = Mage::registry("torque_product_collection"); in the block class contains nothing or null. On the controller when I var_dump it, there are values.

Comment: Yes, the main problem is redirection, so registry value got lost from the first request.
You can save in the session, I corrected the code above.

Comment: Thanks @Marko Novakovic. I've used session to send data from controller to block. However, session can't handle large collection of data because it has certain limit, so I put the collection to the block. Please update your answer before I accept it. Just transfer the product collection in the block. Thanks again.

Comment: One more request. do you have any idea about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32733655/magento-programmatically-create-custom-product-attribute-via-set-up-script. Thanks!